# Delimeter range lines functions

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line, sed

I have

```
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
}
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
}
define host {
  aaa
  ddd
```

I want to do is:

```
for i in $([awk][sed] xxxxxxxx file) ; do grep "xxxxx" $i ; done
```

where each iteration is a function

1)

```
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
}
```

2)

```
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
}
```

3)

```
define host {
  aaa
  ddd
}
```

To do this I try to use awk, sed. But I do not work well

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need like this ?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="}\n"} /ccc/{print $0}' file
```

Output:

```
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` with custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='}\n*' 'RT{print "(" NR ")", ORS $0 RT}' file

(1)
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
}

(2)
define host {
  aaa
  bbb
  ccc
}

(3)
define host {
  aaa
  ddd
}
```

`(1)` or `(2)` or `(3)` are record numbers here that you can omit from output with

```
awk -v RS='}\n*' 'RT{print $0 RT}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grep on your functions, why don't you just use :

```
$ sed -n '/{/,/}/{/bbb/p}' file
bbb
bbb
```

It loops over function blocks (from lines containing `{` to next line containing `}`) and print maching text.